# Laravel WhereDate Filter in Auth User Time zone

Tags: laravel, timezone, php-carbon

My default Laravel application timezone is `America/Los_Angeles (pst)`, I'm storing all the timestamps like `created_at` with this timezone in database.

In the user profile, we are providing options to select a timezone. While showing the list of data for example in trip listing I'm converting & showing created at as per user selected time zone ( `$date->setTimezone($user->timezone);`)

For example, if the trip Id `197` has `created_at` 2020-06-11 23:00:00 stored in db (as per default application timezone i.e. pst) while in the listing I'm showing 2020-06-12 02:00:00 (est timezone as per user profile 3 hrs ahead).

Now everything works fine until I had to add date range (start & end date) filter in the listing. The problem is if I'm selecting start date 2020-10-12 in the filter, in result it is not getting `197` trip id because in the database it is stored as 2020-06-11 23:00:00., this 197 id record should be there in listing after filter because as per auth user timezone the trip is added on 2020-06-12. My DB query is `$trips->whereDate('created_at', '>=' ,$request->start_date);`. I have the only date and not time in request for filter trips I need to somehow pass timezone in this query or is there any better solution for this. The date filter should work as per user selected timezone

Comment: You can set the database's timezone via [`\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\MySqlConnector\::configureTimezone()`](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.html#method_configureTimezone). This only works for `timestamp` columns, not for `datatime` columns.

Comment: while fetching data i'm trying to get it as per user profile timezone.

Comment: I hardly know any other way, to bring the timezone into SQL and that's where you need it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if anyone faced a similar problem following is the answer I found Generally for date range filters you’ll want to make sure you’re setting the start dates time to 00:00 and the end dates time to 23:59

```
if($request->filled('start_date'))
{
    // $request->start_date;
    $date = Carbon::parse($request->start_date, auth()->user()->timezone)
        ->startOfDay()
        ->setTimezone(config('app.timezone'));

    $brokers->where('created_at', '>=' ,$date);
}

if($request->filled('end_date'))
{
    $end_date = Carbon::parse($request->end_date, auth()->user()->timezone)
        ->endOfDay()
        ->setTimezone(config('app.timezone'));
    $brokers->where('created_at', '<=' ,$end_date);
}
```

Comment: It's correct approach but in this case, you must use `where` (and not `whereDate`) to take the time into account.

Comment: Hi ```whereDate``` is working fine in my code as filters are datepicker only

Comment: Because you check from Los_Angeles I think, double-check with timezones before and after as whereDate truncate the date so your startOfDay/endOfDay is not properly handled.

Answer (score 0):

When you can have different timezones for 1 column in a table, you need [dateTimeTz](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-dateTimeTz) to store both datetime + timezone for each row.

With this, the `whereDate` will use the timezone stored, then you can reconvert to any other timezone on need without loss.

Comment: i search a lot coudn't find an example for ```dateTimeTz``` , can you share one example for it

Comment: thanks for guiding , really appreciate all the support. following is the answer i found out